# How to get response data of a pdf file in python

Tags: python, download, python-requests

I am trying to fetch the data of a pdf file available online
I have tried

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://imdagrimet.gov.in/sites/default/files/daas_bulletin/District%20Advisory%20patna_17.pdf")
print(response.content)
```

but it gives a byte object as a response, and I am not able to decode that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the data inside a file in order to be able to get it.

Like this:

```
with open('/District_Advisory_patna_17.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your data to file:

```
import requests
import shutil


url = 'your url'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```